# Extending Dropwizard Service class in Clojure

Tags: java, rest, clojure, dropwizard

I've been using Dropwizard to write RESTful APIs in Scala for a while now, and I'd really like to use it in Clojure.

What I am trying to do is create a subclass of `com.yammer.dropwizard.Service`, which I can instantiate and run in my `-main`, and I am struggling to make this happen.

So far as I know, my options are:

1. `gen-class` in `ns` declaration. Not feasible because I want to build macros (such as `defservice`), which I can't use in the `ns` declaration. Unless there's some way to generate a thing at runtime and pass it to `compile`, but that seems like a filthy hack.
2. `gen-class` outside `ns`. Despite [some code I found](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html), it seems that this doesn't work at all. Here's a simple example:

   ```
   user> (gen-class :name foo :extends Object)
   nil
   user> (foo.)
   Unable to resolve classname: foo
    [Thrown class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
   ```

   I am aware that `gen-class` only works at compile time. I dropped this into a file and put `(foo.` into my `-main`, and I got the same exception.
3. `proxy`. This seems to be the most promising, and it works for simple cases, but not when extending Dropwizard's `Service` class:

   ```
   user> (proxy [Object] [])
   #<Object$0 user.proxy$java.lang.Object$0@249faafc>
   user> (import [com.yammer.dropwizard Service])
   com.yammer.dropwizard.Service
   user> (proxy [Service] ["x"])
   java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
     [Thrown class java.lang.ClassCastException]
   ```

   I think this may be due to `Service` taking a type parameter, but I could not find any information about dealing with this in Clojure. What I did find seemed to indicate that these were only meaningful to javac, and ignored by Clojure. So perhaps I am incorrect about why this is happening.
4. `deftype`. Doesn't work because `Service` is a class, and `deftype` only works on interfaces and protocols.

I think I'm on the right track, but am missing some of the subtleties of how `gen-class` and/or `proxy` work, and the Clojure documentation is extremely terse. How can I extend this Java class in Clojure?

Comment: Clojure can normally proxy an object that takes generic parameters (try `(proxy [java.util.ArrayList] [])`). Your current problem is due to the implementation of `com.yammer.dropwizard.AbstractService` and especially the call to `getConfigurationClass` inside the constructor.

Based on a quick look the class hierarchy of Dropwizard seems highly odd.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use option 1, but unless I misinterpret your description, it sounds like you're trying to write code inside the namespace form? This isn't what you want. When you add a gen-class to the namespace form, a Java class will be generated for that whole namespace. You can then over-ride methods by naming your functions in that ns with a -prefix (or chose another one and use :method-prefix).

Here's an example. I don't know enough about the libraries you're using to test it with those classes but it should be at least similar:

```
(ns com.myapp.MyService
  (:gen-class
   :extends com.yammer.dropwizard.Service
   :exposes-methods {someSuperClassMethod someLocalAlias}))

;; now just write your code as normal, note that
;; you can access super-class methods with the exposes-methods
;; map above!

;; prefix your overriden methods with -

(defn -overriddenMethod
  [params]
  ... )
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The main problem with this is that it requires authors of services to drop boilerplate into their (ns …). What I want is to have `defservice` which generate the appropriate `gen-class` (or whatever). I guess this method would be acceptable if it was the only one that would work, but it is far from how I want it to be.